# Reveal.js not initialising in vue except on refresh

Tags: javascript, axios, vuejs3, vue-router, reveal.js

I'm creating a Vue app to read comic books via Reveal.js. The component takes the data from the parent. there is an Axios call in the parent to provide the data from a rest API. I'm also using Vue router with the createWebHashHistory setup as I'm using a Django backend to provide the API.

If I refresh the page it will load the presentation correctly but when I navigate to the page it doesn't seem to initialise Reveal. there are no errors in the console.

I've tried to watch the route changing and other events to run Reveals sync or initialise but I've not had any success.

**component**

```
<template>
  <div class="reveal" id="comic_box" ref="comic_box">
    <div id="slides_div" class="slides">
      <section v-for="(page, index) in comic_data.pages" :key="page.index" :data-menu-title="page.page_file_name">
        <img :data-src="'/image/' + comic_data.selector + '/' + page.index " class="w-100"  :alt="page.page_file_name">
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Reveal from "reveal.js";

export default {
  name: "TheComicReader",
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  props: {
    comic_data: Object
  },
  methods: {
  },
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      Reveal.initialize()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    Reveal.initialize()
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

**comic_data**

```
{
  "selector": "e1b76b93-814c-4ee8-9104-8c8187977836",
  "title": "Batman 125 (2022) (digital-SD).cbr",
  "last_read_page": 0,
  "pages": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "page_file_name": "Batman 125-000.jpg",
      "content_type": "image/jpeg"
    },
    {
      "index": 1,
      "page_file_name": "Batman 125-001.jpg",
      "content_type": "image/jpeg"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I noticed that the DOM elements in Reveal were not updating after moving away from the page. I solved this by forcing Reveal to bind to the new comic_box by ref. This is now consistently loading the presentation correctly.

```
  mounted () {
    Reveal(this.$refs.comic_box).initialize()
  }
```